# Como fazer um elemento acompanhar a barra de rolagem?

Tags: html, css, rolamento

Como faço para deixar meu menu fixo de acordo com a rolagem?

Fiz um *snippet* para exemplificar o código. Eu abro o menu, quando eu rolo a página ele fica na posição dele. Quero que o menu acompanhe a rolagem da página.

Como posso fazer isso?

```js
var nav = document.getElementById("menu");
var showMenu = document.getElementById("abrir");
var hideMenu = document.getElementById("fechar");
showMenu.addEventListener("click", function() {
  nav.classList.add("show");
});

hideMenu.addEventListener("click", function() {
  nav.classList.remove("show");
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#site {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
#fundo_site {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: -292px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  transition: left 0.5s linear;
}
#img_menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#menu.show {
  left: 0;
}
#bt_menu {
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
  margin: 15px;
}
p {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  left: 10px;
  top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Meu Site</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="site">
    <img id="fundo_site" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gINau.jpg.jpg">
    <a id="abrir" style="position:absolute;">
      <img id="bt_menu" src="img/bt.png">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="menu">
    <p id="fechar" style="position:absolute;"><strong>X</strong>
    </p>
    <img id="img_menu" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiAvt.jpg.jpg">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **position: fixed;** no seletor **#menu**.

```js
  var nav = document.getElementById("menu");
  var showMenu = document.getElementById("abrir");
  var hideMenu = document.getElementById("fechar");
  showMenu.addEventListener("click", function () {
    nav.classList.add("show");
  });

  hideMenu.addEventListener("click", function () {
    nav.classList.remove("show");
  });
```

```css
 html, body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 } 

 #site{  
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  
 }

 #fundo_site{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 }

 #menu{
  left: -292px;
  height:100%;
  width:15%;
  transition: left 0.5s linear;
  position: fixed;
 }

 #img_menu{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }

 #menu.show{
  left:0;
 }

 #bt_menu{
  width:20%;
  height:20%;
  margin: 15px;
 }


 p{
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;   
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  left: 10px;
  top: -5px;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Meu Site</title>

  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  
 

</head>
<body>
 

 <div id="site">
   <img id="fundo_site" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gINau.jpg.jpg">
   <a id="abrir" style="position:absolute;"> <img id="bt_menu" src="img/bt.png"></a>
 </div>
 


  <div id="menu">  
  <p id="fechar" style="position:absolute;"><strong>X</strong></p>
  <img id="img_menu" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiAvt.jpg.jpg">
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Que coisa superhipermega siiiimples heheheh, Obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Apenas faça o seguinte, no seu código do CSS `#menu` em `position` troque o código `absolute` por `fixed`.

```css
    #menu{
  position: fixed;
  left: -292px;
  height:100%;
  width:15%;
  transition: left 0.5s linear;
 }
```

Comment: Como sou novo não tenho previlégios para sugerir a correção da resposta anterior, então respondi com outra pergunta. Espero que o amigo Yure não se ofenda.